# Как правильно передать POST запрос?

Tags: php, bitcoin

Пытаюсь передать данные в JSON для создания кошелька на [bitaps](https://developer.bitaps.com/forwarding#%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Но постоянно выдаёт ошибку 405: Method Not Allowed, подскажите пожалуйста, из-за чего это может быть?

```
    $options=json_encode(array(
      'forwarding_address'=>'bc1qhlknxc3yqu6z6qy64aascvn23tc8zapc46ynag',
      'callback_link'=>'https://testshopbot.ru/recieve.php',
      'confirmations'=>1
    ));

    $ch = curl_init('https://api.bitaps.com/btc/v1/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($options));

    $response= curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    var_dump($response);
```

Comment: в той же документации поле forwarding_address, а не  address

Comment: и данные передаются в json

Comment: Исправил как вы сказали, но ошибка та же
и добавилось предупреждение
Warning: http_build_query() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given
string(23) "405: Method Not Allowed"

Comment: естественно, что http_build_query делать не надо, надо передавать заголовок типа отправляемых данных, в доке же написано application/json